# htaccess ErrorDocument 404 redirect to another domain not working

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I want to redirect all 404's to another domain

my htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com%{REQUEST_URI}
```

That last line is my attempt to do it but looks like it is conflicting with the `RewriteRule . /index.php`.

If I remove that redirect rule the 404 redirect works but all subpages (/contact, etc) stop working, and when I have my config as above, the 404 are not working - this is what I get:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Apparently

> it is not possible to use a custom 404 ErrorDocument directive in your
> htaccess file because WordPress' index.php will always be found when
> processing the htaccess content.

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/207618/override-404-page-with-htaccess

will have to try another way